# Recover Outlook Data from old HDD without starting Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, microsoft-outlook, data-recovery

I have Outlook on my Windows machine.

Windows is crashed, so no chance to get the Outlook data from a normal working backUp there.

Is it possible to get the Outlook files and load the files into another Windows?

(I hope my goal is understandable, I want to know if there are copy-able Outlook files, copy them and insert them to another Outlook because the Outlook is not starting anymore in the reason the Windows in which the Outlook is installed is not starting anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the mail data, go looking for .PST and .OST files on the disk.  .PSTs should easily mount in another copy of Outlook.  I don't know how you mount .OSTs, but I suspect google can help there.

Answer (score 1):

Try any live cd

- [Ubuntu live](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)
- [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)
- [Hirens
  Bootcd](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)

to boot into your machine and copy the .pst and .ost files on your machine to a usb drive

Comment: Do you now where this files are?

Comment: which version of windows are you using ?

Comment: C:\Users\Specific User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook